# geoserver to openlayers wfst

Tags: javascript, openlayers

i want to bring my geoserver layer in open layers using the below code however i am not able to get the correct url format for entering the following layer url---
localhost:8080/geoserver/itachi/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=itachi%3Awfs_geom&maxFeatures=50

```
var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({            
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('https://gsx.geolytix.net/geoserver/geolytix_wfs/ows', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'wfs_geom',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
        });
    },
```

Comment: Are you asking how load a url without bbox?

Comment: yess.. i have an empty table with no records only id and geometry column i want to publish it in geoserver with wfst capability so that everytime i draw a new feature on my application it gets saved in the postgis database table.i am able to this with this url"https://gsx.geolytix.net/geoserver/geolytix_wfs/ows'' however when i provide my above mentioned localhost address it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it using the full url

```
var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/itachi/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=itachi%3Awfs_geom&maxFeatures=50',
    format: formatWFS
});
```

But if you need to change projections (e.g. data is returned in EPSG:4326 and view is EPSG:3857) you will need to use a loader

```
var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function () {
        $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/itachi/ows', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.0.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'itachi:wfs_geom',
                maxFeatures: '50'
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response),{
                dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            });
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
});
```

If data can be updated you will need to call `sourceWFS.refresh();` to reload